# R Shiny app .httr-oauth behaves differently on a docker than in a server or locally

Tags: r, docker, shiny, analytics

I have developed an R Shiny app which uses google analytics. I simply use ga_auth with ga_id to allow access to google analytics.  This works well on my Mac with R Shiny, and an ubuntu EC2 server.  The code is as below:

```
ga_auth("./.httr-oauth")
ga_id <- 8888888888
```

It accesses a previously generated .httr-oauth file and I get access to the google analytics API as expected

However, running the same code in a Docker, it produces hangs the app, and generates the following log message :

> *Waiting for authentication in browser...
>   Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
>   Please point your browser to the following url: 
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=289......*

The app simply needs a basic access to the analytics api, and clearly I do not need the user to have to interact with google authentication themselves.  Any ideas?  I have looked at several articles on the subject but none that clearly highlight the difference in behaviour between a docker and server app with respect to http-oauth.

Please help!  This is my first posting (the first tine I have got this stuck!) so my apologies if I haven't got things quite right!  I was inspired by a talk from a Stack Overflow employee at the recent EARL conference in London!

Alex